# django Queryset filter(a__b__c=d): get hold of b for further filtering

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am writing a method that computes a complex Django `QuerySet`.
It starts like this

```
qs1 = A.objects.filter(b_set__c_obj__user=user)
```

- `qs1` will eventually become the result, but before it does, the method goes on with several further steps of filtering and annotation.
- `b_set` is an 1:n relationship, but I know that at most one of the `c_obj` can actually match.
- I need to reference this `c_obj`, because I need another attribute `email` from it for one of the filtering steps (which is against instances of another model `D` selected based on `c_obj`'s `email`).
- `user` can be either a `User` model instance or an `OuterRef` Django ORM expression, because the whole queryset created by the method is subsequently also to be used in a subquery.
- Therefore, any solution that involves *evaluating* querysets is not suitable for me. I can only *build* a single queryset.

Hmm?

Comment: You can filter with the same `c_obj` with `A.object.filter(b_set__c_obj__atr1=val1, b_set__c_obj__atr2=val2)`, so if you write these in the *same* `.filter(..)` it will only make two JOINs here, and not twice a `JOIN` to each referred model (four `JOIN`s thus).

Answer (score 0):

> I need to reference this `c_obj`, because I need another attribute email from it for one of the filtering steps (which is against instances of another model D selected based on `c_obj`'s email).

If you do all the filtering with the *same* [**`.filter(…)`** clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) then that `c_obj` will be the same for all conditions. In other words if you want to filter `A` such that it has a related `B` and a related `C` for example that has as `email='foo@bar.com'`, and as `type='user'`, you can filter with:

```
qs1 = A.objects.filter(
    b_set__c_obj__email='foo@bar.com',
    b_set__c_obj__type='user'
)
```

This is thus different from:

```
qs1 = A.objects.filter(
    b_set__c_obj__email='foo@bar.com'
).filter(
    b_set__c_obj__type='user'
)
```

since here it will look for an `A` object that has a related `c_obj` with `email='foo@bar.com` and for a `c_obj` (*not* per se the *same* one) with `type='user'`.

Comment: This does not help solve my problem, due to item 3 in my question. 
Thanks however for such an _incredibly_ fast response! 
I have not solved my problem, but have overcome it: I found a way to _avoid_ the need to get hold of `c_obj`.